# TLS & trust all certs from IT side, not java code

Tags: java, ssl-certificate, tls1.2

```
Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(port);
HTTPConduit httpConduit = (HTTPConduit) client.getConduit();
TLSClientParameters tlsParams = new TLSClientParameters();
tlsParams.setSecureSocketProtocol(TLSv1.2);
tlsParams.setKeyManagers(new KeyManager[0]);
tlsParams.setTrustManagers(ALL_CERTIFICATES_TRUST_MANAGERS);
tlsParams.setDisableCNCheck(true);
httpConduit.setTlsClientParameters(tlsParams);
```

Exist any possibility to do the above functionality from server/IT confirguration side (not java code)?

I guess that instead of trust all certs, I may import the particular cert to keystore (on  server), but... what about TLS?

Is it a mandatory to have  'tlsParams.setSecureSocketProtocol(TLSv1.2)'  in code or maybe is possible to do it from server/OS side?

Comment: Your question is hard to understand. If you control the server and the client *and* you don't want security then just don't use SSL. Using SSL and then defeating the security at every turn just means you pay the encryption tax but get none of its benefits.

Comment: I don't need any additional security (test environment). Earlier (without the above code) everything worked fine (only ssl certificate in keystore on my side). But now, something changed (TLS 1.2 instead of SSL v3) on server side. I am wonder if exist only one way to fix this case (the above code) or maybe exist a chance to change something in server/os configuration without deployment of code ?